# How to print one random fact with picture of certain category from Wikipedia?

Tags: python, api, wikipedia

I want to print summary of one random fact/topic with picture of certain category from Wikipedia.

I have tried this:

```
import requests


def get_wikipedia_summary_and_image(topic):
    # Make a request to the Wikipedia API to get the summary and image of the given topic
    response = requests.get(f"https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/{topic}")

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Extract the summary and image from the response
        summary = response.json()['extract']
        image = response.json()['thumbnail']['source']

        # Print the summary and image
        print(summary)
        print(image)
    else:
        print("An error occurred while fetching the summary and image.")


# Example usage
get_wikipedia_summary_and_image("Double-slit experiment")
```

But I want to randomize the topic of certain category. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia offers a API/URL to get a random article:

```py
# This will redirect you
resp = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random")
# Get the redirect URL
# Extract the wiki title
title = resp.url.split('/wiki/')[-1]

get_wikipedia_summary_and_image(title)
```

Comment: But How to do this on certain category (like: physics experiment)?

Comment: How would you get the category data?

Comment: using parameter params = {
    'action': 'query',
    'format': 'json',
    'list': 'categorymembers',
    'cmtitle': category_title,
    'cmlimit': 'max'  # Set the maximum number of results to retrieve
} , But I am searching for other methods. using this I can't find my desirable result